# How do i avoid Chrome to display the confirmation message before close the window?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have an iframe (a google drive form) in my site. When i try to move to another page, the browser shows a message to confirm if i "want to close the window, its possible to lost the changes made".

I am using a javascript, and works on mozilla but not in google chrome

```
    function cierra_ventana()
    {
    window.open('','_parent','');
    window.close();
    }
```

Comment: and we're supposed to know the problem without any code? please post your code .

Comment: function cierra_ventana()
{
window.open('','_parent','');
window.close();
}